# while loop inside while loop to confirm to delete

Tags: python-3.x

```
[1] Enter 1 to display all student record.
[2] Enter 2 to delete the student record.
[q] Enter q to back to the menu.
>>: 2
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+--------+
|    |   Student ID | Full Name   |   Age | Sex    |
|----+--------------+-------------+-------+--------|
|  0 |            1 | bob         |    10 | male   |
|  1 |            2 | mia         |    10 | female |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+--------+
Enter student index to delete: 0                        # user input to delete index of 0
Are you sure? [Y]/[N]: y                                # user input to confirm to delete student record
Delete completed

[1] Enter 1 to display all student record.
[2] Enter 2 to delete the student record.
[q] Enter q to back to the menu.
>>: 1
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+--------+
|    |   Student ID | Full Name   |   Age | Sex    |
|----+--------------+-------------+-------+--------|
|  0 |            1 | bob         |    10 | male   |    # index 0 still exist
|  1 |            2 | mia         |    10 | female |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+--------+
```

Below is my code. I'm not sure did I do it right or not. Obviously I do it wrong.
If user **enter 2 to delete student record**, it will show **'Enter student index to delete.'** and print out **'Are you sure? [Y/N]'** for confirmation. If user enter [Y] it will delete index 0. However in my case, if I enter [Y] to delete, student record still exist. Thank you :)

```
def deleteStudent():
    global record
    choice = ''
    while choice != 'q':
        print('[1] Enter 1 to display all student record.')
        print('[2] Enter 2 to delete the student record.')
        print('[q] Enter q to back to the menu.')

        choice = input('>>: ')
        if choice == '1':
            if len(record) <= 0:
                print('No record available')
            if len(record) > 0:
                print(tabulate(record, headers = ['Student ID', 'Full Name', 'Age', 'Sex'], tablefmt = 'psql', showindex = True))
        elif choice == '2':
            if len(record) > 0:
                print(tabulate(record, headers = ['Student ID', 'Full Name', 'Age', 'Sex'], tablefmt = 'psql', showindex = True))
            
            index = input('Enter student index to delete: ')
            while True:
                if int(index) == record:
                    del record[int(index)]
                sure = True
                while sure:
                    sure = input('Are you sure? [Y]/[N]: ')
                    if sure == 'y' or sure == 'Y':
                        print('Delete completed')
                        break
                    elif sure == 'n' or sure == 'N':
                        break
                    break
        elif choice == 'q':
            break
```

Comment: This is always false: `if int(index) == record`. Record is a list, index is a number.

Comment: I already changed to `if index == record` but still cannot find whats wrong with my code.

Comment: I think you already got this. You need to indent in one of the `break` statement. The one before the `elif choice == 'q'`. Good luck with your fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `record` is a list and `index` is an integer. The correct logic is to check if the `index` is valid, then delete that entry from the `record`.

Try this code:

```python
def deleteStudent():
    global record
    choice = ''
    while choice != 'q':
        print('[1] Enter 1 to display all student record.')
        print('[2] Enter 2 to delete the student record.')
        print('[q] Enter q to back to the menu.')

        choice = input('>>: ')
        if choice == '1':
            if len(record) <= 0:
                print('No record available')
            if len(record) > 0:
                print(tabulate(record, headers = ['Student ID', 'Full Name', 'Age', 'Sex'], tablefmt = 'psql', showindex = True))
        elif choice == '2':
            if len(record) > 0:
                print(tabulate(record, headers = ['Student ID', 'Full Name', 'Age', 'Sex'], tablefmt = 'psql', showindex = True))
            
            index = input('Enter student index to delete: ')
            while True:
                if int(index) < len(record):
                    sure = True
                    while sure:
                        sure = input('Are you sure? [Y]/[N]: ')
                        if sure == 'y' or sure == 'Y':
                            del record[int(index)]
                            print('Delete completed')
                            break
                        elif sure == 'n' or sure == 'N':
                            break
                        break
                    break
        elif choice == 'q':
            break
```

Comment: one of the break has to be indented out. The one before `elif choice == 'q'`

Answer (score 0):

not sure what is record but if ti's not integer this line will give you False all the time:

```
if int(index) == record
```

another thing, you probably would like to move the delete record after you ask the user to confirm that he's sure

Comment: `record = [] # empty list outside function`
I already changed to `if index == record` but the index that I want to remove still exist.